# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable how to use attributes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Beginner web-scraping getting error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```py
res=requests.get("https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

image_quote=soup.find('img', {'class':'p-qotd bqPhotoDefault bqPhotoDefaultFw img-responsive'})

print(image_quote['alt'])
```

I expected the output as the quote of the day. Instead getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# getting HTML from the Google Play web page
res=requests.get("https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
image_quote = soup.find('img', {'class':'p-qotd'})
print(image_quote['alt'])
# print(soup)
```

Your code doesn't work because you have specified all classes. Just specify the unique class